# Liferay aui auto fields delete button not working

Tags: liferay-6, liferay-aui, autofield

[image]

Aui Auto Fields delete button is **not working**  well. However add button works as it is.

Here is configuration code I have used:

```
AUI().use('liferay-auto-fields',function(A) {
    new Liferay.AutoFields({
           contentBox: '#clientContact',
           fieldIndexes: namespace + 'clientContactIndexs',
           on: {
                'init':function(event) {
                    console.log('init');
                },
                'clone': function(event) {
                    console.log('clone');
                    console.log(event);
                },
                'delete': function(event) {
                    console.log('delete');
                    console.log(event);
                }
            }
       }).render();
   });
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="clientContact">         
            <div class="lfr-form-row lfr-form-row-inline">
                <div class="row-fields">
                    <aui:row>
                        <aui:column cssClass="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                            <aui:input name="clientContactName1" id="clientContactName1" label="" placeholder="client.contact.name">
                                <aui:validator name="required"></aui:validator>
                            </aui:input>
                        </aui:column>
                        <aui:column cssClass="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                            <aui:input name="clientContactMobile1" id="clientContactMobile1" label="" placeholder="mobile">
                            </aui:input>
                        </aui:column>
                        <aui:column cssClass="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                            <aui:input name="clientContactEmail1" id="clientContactEmail1" label="" placeholder="email">
                            </aui:input>
                        </aui:column>
                    </aui:row>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Is there anything I'm missing?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some solution to this problem.
I know this **is not the best solutions** and it **should work properly without any kind of manual code**. But even though everything's fine, and your code is not working **THEN and ONLY THEN** you should try the below-given code.

```
$(".delete-row").click(function(){
    if($("#clientContact > .lfr-form-row").length > 1){
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
    }
});
```

It will remove the row on which delete button is clicked.